# Service Fabric service exists but returns 404 upon calling

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric cluster that works fine locally but when deployed to azure the WebAPI stateless service returns

```
404 FABRIC_E_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXISTS
```

However the SF cluster shows that the service actually does exists and is up and running
Below is my service manifest for the service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="SvcWebAPIPkg"
             Version="1.0.9"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ServiceTypes>
<!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
     This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in 
Program.cs. -->
<StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="SvcWebAPIType" />
</ServiceTypes>

<!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.9">
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>SvcWebApi.exe</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>


</CodePackage>

  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.9" />

   <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
    <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" 
      Port="80" />

    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: What address do you use to access the service?

Comment: http://myaddress.com/api/BriefcaseApi/GetString/ @Mardoxx this is a simple get call to a self hosted WebAPI inside the cluster

Answer (score 0):

If that's the way how you access your service - "myaddress.com/api/BriefcaseApi/GetString" - it's incorrect. SF tries to resolve 'api' as a registered service, which is obviously does not exist. Right?  Here is the way how you should construct the url -

```
http(s)://<Cluster FQDN | internal IP>:Port/<ServiceInstanceName>/<Suffix path>?PartitionKey=<key>&PartitionKind=<partitionkind>&ListenerName=<listenerName>&TargetReplicaSelector=<targetReplicaSelector>&Timeout=<timeout_in_seconds>
```

In your case, here is how it may look like -

http(s)://myaddress.com/SvcWebAPI/api/BriefcaseApi/GetString

Find more info here - [Reverse proxy in Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy).

Comment: Service already exists as its a default service, so I donot have to construct the url using reverse proxy.

Comment: @Kayani I'd like to take a look at your listener configuration and SF cluster manifest. It might be working locally if the request gets routed directly to the machine without making a round trip through LB.